# Presenting a new viewController doesn't seem to unload the previous

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

The game I'm developing consists of a Main Menu, and Game viewController separately.

However when moving from the game screen to the menu screen, it seems as if the class files from the previous viewController are still in effect?

For example, players start the game by tapping anywhere on the screen whilst in the game viewController, which causes a new bar to be "launched", which in turn plays a small tone which varies depending on the direction. However when returning to the main menu after the game is over (achieved by pressing a button to present the menu viewController), tapping anywhere on the menu screen seems to start the game again from the game viewController?

By this, I mean the bar launch sound is played, despite there being no code available in the main menu viewController to play said sound, pressing play on the menu will take you to the game screen, where the game has been reset, until tapping again, where the sound plays implying a new bar is launched, despite all images being invisible.

I made sure that, when leaving any view, I wipe all subviews from the view, so that whenever the screen is loaded there's nothing being covered up. I also tried dismissing the previous view controller, however nothing seems to take effect. So, I can't tell for certain whether the views are being removed or what... It's simply mind breaking to me.

Unfortunately my descriptions most likely aren't doing myself any justice, so hopefully this video demonstration will help out. Note that at the beginning, I am tapping the screen to show that no sound is played, however of course that won't be visible.

Edit: You'll notice that when returning to the menu, tapping the screen seems to mess up the moving bar in the background, despite the gameBarMovement timer being invalidated upon moving from the game to the menu. The fact that they're using separate class files also should mean the bars shouldn't be effected? Knowing me, I've missed something fairly obvious.

Answer (score 0):

This is how the UIViewController life-cycle works as far as I know. UIViewcontrollers aren't unloaded until the app starts running out of memory. What you probably need is some way, in your game VC, to stop the game loop from running and resume it once a new game is started.

Comment: I have the gameBarMovement timer, which I hope you know its purpose for xD

After that, there's the bool for gameStarted and gameOver, which all of which are correctly set when moving back.

It's awfully confusing

Comment: EDIT: Saw your edit now. Make sure these `BOOL`s are the value that you expect in the game loop. Common scenario is that you set the value of a property on an instance which is nil, I've had that happen to me countless times.

Comment: Just seems strange to me that the class file would still be taken in to account, even in a completely different viewController?

Comment: It probably means that someone is still holding a reference to the game view controller. But again, from my experience it's not uncommon for views to only load once (`viewDidLoad` being called once per run) since it reduces load times to keep them in memory.

Comment: Is there no way to manually unload a view? I'm aware of dismissing the viewController, but that doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: Make sure all references to the VC are set to nil.

Comment: Get ready for a stupid response, but how is that achieved? Unless I've simply never heard that wording.

Comment: Edit: Very strange, so now that I set the viewController's to nil upon leaving, it seems like the sound from the menu plays.. whilst in the game..

Comment: That is weird, did it solve the first issue? If so, perhaps the same technique can be used here as well?

Comment: Unfortunately not, if anything sound is overlapping from both views now. I'm thinking of making a global variable?